# Hyper-V Won’t Start VM

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v, windows-server-2019, nested-virtualization

I am using Hyper-V on my windows 10 pro laptop, inside of it I am created a Windows Server 2019 Datacenter Evaluation VM. Later on, inside of this I put AD DS on this as well as Hyper-V (inside the server) for making more VMs, as per class requirements.

Essentially the structure is:

- Windows 10 pro (my laptop)
- Hyper-V
- Windows Server 2019 Datacenter
- Active directory Domain Service
- Hyper-V
- Windows 10 Consumer VM

I was able to make a new VM inside Hyper- V that is inside a Windows 2019 server (that is also inside Hyper-V) for Windows 10, but when I go to boot it up it gives this error:

```
**The application encountered an error while attempting to change the state of 'Win-10-1'**
*'Win-10-1' failed to start.*
Failed to start the virtual machine 'Win-10-1' because one of the Hyper-V components is not running.
```

Virtualization is enabled in my BIOS. Hyper-V, Hyper-V Management Tools, Windows Hypervisor Platform, and Hyper-V Platform are enabled. Hyper-V Host Compute Service and Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management are running.

I’m not quite sure what the issue is. Is there some kind of setting in Hyper-V Manager that needs to be check marked for nested-virtualization?

The goal is for this Windows 10 consumer VM to run properly.

Comment: Have you enabled nested virtualization? Which is required since your running a VM within another VM

Comment: [Verify your hardware and VM configuration is correct and compatible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/system-center/vmm/vm-nested-virtualization?view=sc-vmm-2022)

Comment: @Ramhound how would I do that, in Hyper-V? If it’s the setting in BIOS, it’s already enabled.

Comment: I linked you to the instructions.  You have to enable it for the primary VM then again within the guest VM on that VM. You have simple enabled it on the host.